# Delete single product from Facebook Product Catalog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm working on adding Dynamic Product Ads to our app. I've created a Product Catalog through the Facebook Business Manager and successfully uploaded a CSV file of our entire product catalog. I'm also in the process of setting up a daily refresh of the products.

My question is - how do I make an immediate `DELETE` request for a specific product? If a user deletes a product I don't want to wait a whole day for the product feed to be refreshed and risk the user seeing an ad for a deleted product. The docs make it seem like that isn't supported... but I can't believe that's the case.

Relevant from the Facebook docs:

- [Update Invidividual Product](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-catalog/v2.9#update-a-product)
- [Product Item Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-item) (I think this is deprecated - DELETE request to `/{product_item_id}` did not succeed).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the rules in Product Sets to exclude that product/s and then working with the Product Sets with the ads.

Answer (score 0):

I got the product OFF facebook by editing the data source CSV, and under the availability column, I added discontinued. That removed it from Facebook after being imported from shopify.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late to the party.

I'm actually coping with this right now, and the only thing I can find in the API stating about *individual products* is actually when it comes to the [Catalog Batch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch/)

> To send item updates, use the `/{catalog_id}/batch` endpoint.
>
> To create, update, or delete items in your catalog, make an HTTP POST
> call to:
> **https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<CATALOG_ID>/batch?requests=**